# Objective C method naming convention

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am currently using the following conventions

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString *) name;

+ (NSString *) aliasForName:(NSString *) name

- (void) method

- (void) methodWithApple:(NSString *) apple andOrange:(NSString *) orange
andMango:(NSString *) mango

- (void) statusWasChanged:(id)sender
```

Do you have a better style for the above methods?

Thanks

Comment: For `initWithName` make sure you understand how ARC will treat this (i.e. returning a retained object)

Comment: your naming convention is good..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) is a great resource for answering any naming convention questions.  My answer is as much as possible based off of this.

## Init Method

The init method looks good.

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString *) name;
```

## Class Method

The class method looks good.

```
+ (NSString *) aliasForName:(NSString *) name
```

Class methods can also be used to instantiate an instance of an object.  In this instance, Apple's API's generally have the method start with the name of the class like [`UIButton`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)'s [`buttonWithType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW38) method that has the signature:

```
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
```

## Instance Methods

Good resource for coding conventions for methods can be found under [General Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001751-BCIJHEDH).

The following method should drop the `"and"`s:

```
- (void) methodWithApple:(NSString *) apple andOrange:(NSString *) orange
andMango:(NSString *) mango  // BAD
```

> Don’t use “and” to link keywords that are attributes of the receiver.
>
> `- (int)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path file:(NSString *) name types:(NSArray *)fileTypes;` **right**
>
> `- (int)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path andFile:(NSString *)name andTypes:(NSArray *)fileTypes;` **wrong**

The signature should look more like the following:

```
- (void) methodWithApple:(NSString*)apple orange:(NSString*)orange
mango:(NSString*)mango  // GOOD
```

## [Delegate Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001803-BCIDAIJE)

Lastly, I think there are a couple improvements that could be made on what appears to be a delegate method:

```
- (void) statusWasChanged:(id)sender  // Not horrible, but not ideal
```

First improvement is to add the class name to the method.

> Start the name by identifying the class of the object that’s sending
>   the message:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(int)row;
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename;
```

Second improvement is to use `"DidChange"` instead of `"WasChanged"`.

> Use “did” or “will” for methods that are invoked to notify the
>   delegate that something has happened or is about to happen.

```
- (void)browserDidScroll:(NSBrowser *)sender;
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window;
```

Third improvement is strongly casting the sender parameter.  I don't have documentation to support this, however all examples provided in the examples exude this behavior.  Notice the `(NSBrowser*)sender` and `(NSWindow*)window` in the above code sample taken straight from the apple docs.

With this in mind, the delegate method should look more like:

```
- (void) senderClassNameStatusDidChange:(SenderClassName*)sender  // Good
```

If the sender were a Person object it would look like:

```
- (void) personStatusDidChange:(Person*)sender  // Good
```

A word of caution is that you shouldn't always use "did" in delegate methods.

> Although you can use “did” or “will” for methods that are invoked to
>   ask the delegate to do something on behalf of another object, “should”
>   is preferred.

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender;
```

Comment: As Rahul points out, Scott Stevenson's guide to Cocoa conventions is another useful resource when it comes to naming: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

Answer (score 1):

I would say the only one I'm not sure about is:

```
- (void) methodWithApple:(NSString *) apple andOrange:(NSString *) orange
andMango:(NSString *) mango
```

It seems like the "and" in the last two arguments is either unnecessary or should be replaced by a verb.  I think a good name really depends a lot on the context of the call, and what will be done with the parameters sent in.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString *) name;
```

Any method starting with `init` is understood by the framework as a method returning an retained object (difference between `initWithObjectsAndKeys` and `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` for example). So you should use this convention with that in mind, especially when using ARC.

```
+ (NSString *) aliasForName:(NSString *) name
```

Using the same convention, this type of method would return autoreleased objects (static methods or not)

```
- (void) method
```

I would say that if there is only one word, and this word is a noun, it should be the getter of a property (like `view`, `superview`...). Otherwise if it's a verb, why not also add the object it refers to ? Like `closeModalViewController`

```
- (void) methodWithApple:(NSString *) apple andOrange:(NSString *) orange
andMango:(NSString *) mango
```

I would drop the `and` indeed.

```
- (void) statusWasChanged:(id)sender
```

A more Apple-y way would be `statusDidChange:`

Comment: +1  Good answer.  I thought the same thing with the `statusWasChanged:` until I realized the delegate method, which is what I'm assuming that is, is missing the sender's name in it. It should be more like `-(void)senderNameStatusDidChange:(id)sender`. So if the sender was a Person it would be like `-(void)personStatusDidChange:(Person*)person`. The docs on this typically strongly cast the sender as well. See [Delegate Methods][http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001803-BCIDAIJE]

Answer (score 0):

Those are good naming conventions except for the 'and'.  I tend to look at the [Google Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml)'.