# Must multipart method names end in an argument?

Tags: objective-c

For example, the following method works:

```
- (void)feedBackController:(FeedbackController *)controller didReceiveLiveUnlikeComment:(NSString *)commentID;
```

but this next method doesn't:

```
- (void)feedBackController:(FeedbackController *)controller didReceiveLiveLike:;
```

I get the syntax error: "Expected :"

Comment: Related? Duplicate? [Why must the last part of an ObjC method name take an argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4479967) I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a param, you should do:

```
- (void)feedBackControllerDidReceiveLiveLike:(FeedbackController *)controller;
```

For more method naming conventions, check out [Objective C method naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410602/objective-c-method-naming-convention)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to mention the second parameter type and name

or just use id as a type and pass whatever you need

Comment: if you dont want didReceiveLiveLike, then just use - (void)feedBackController:(FeedbackController *)controller;

Comment: else use  - (void)feedBackController:(FeedbackController *)controller didReceiveLiveLike:(id)paramName;